About deformation process of Hamiltonian
I was studying this paper recently, and I do not quite understand its main proof.
In the paper, the inter-site hoppings of the Hamiltonian are described by some $h_k$ loop. On the second page, it stated that the corresponding loop of the Hamiltonian could be continuously deformed into a unit circle, without breaking the property of existence of a zero energy state.
My question:

What does this deformation exactly mean? Suppose I have this real space Hamiltonian written in Toeplitz matrix form, what operator, or other manipulation, should I apply to this matrix to obtain the deformation?

2.I think I understand the first two steps in the proof, but how do I determine a deformation does not cross a critical point (by calculation), and why does such a deformation preserve zero energy edge states?
